# how to use a custom icon in a tooltip baloon using SWT

Tags: swt, tooltip

[image: an example of what i'm tring to do]

as you can see in the tooltip ballon (not the system tray icon) there is an icon of adobe.
tnx allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` which allows you to have any `Composite` as the tooltip.